# Set java path in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, java

I downloaded a tar file and I am untar'ed it and stored it at this location:

> /home/faraz/Desktop/IF/zulu8.38.0.13-ca-jdk8.0.212-linux_x64

I want to run java myjavaclass but I can't. I tried to set it in /etc/environment but that didn't work. I also tried other ways but that file it self doesn't exists.

Can somebody please tell me how to do it?

edit: I didn't install java thru terminal by running a command similar to `sudo apt-get install someversionofjava`. I only downloaded tar file. In Eclipse, I can set Java path easily and all Java programs runs flawlessly inside Eclipse. But if I want to run a java file or jar file thru terminal, that's where I am facing the issues.

> faraz@faraz-HP-ProBook-640-G1:~$ java
>   The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
>    * default-jre
>    * gcj-5-jre-headless
>    * openjdk-8-jre-headless
>    * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
>    * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
>    * openjdk-9-jre-headless
>   Try: sudo apt install

I don't want to install java that way. No.

Comment: fyi: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL as it was a flavor having only 3 years of supported life.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with Unity 7 desktop, server [no desktop] or Kylin) came with 5 years of supported life, all other flavors had only 3 years of supported life.

Comment: guiverc, I love you more than Shane Warne loves John Buchanan. But what on earth what you said has to do with my question?

Comment: @guiverc but thank you anyway

Comment: You've tagged lubuntu, and I'm the lubuntu team member tasked with askubuntu.  If you'd tagged only 16.04 or ubuntu, I'd have said nothing.

Comment: @guiverc I was only kidding bro. I love you.